# iPython: Create variables that depend on the loop index

Tags: variables, loops, jupyter-notebook

Dear Stackoverflow Community,

I am really new to programming so please excuse if I do not get your answers and have to ask again.
I tried to use the search function and I am pretty sure that my problem is a common one, however I do not understand the answers to be honest.

I am using iPython 1.1.0 to run a program named cantera, which is for Combustion modelling. It runs with Python 2.7 if I am correct. My problem is that I want to plot multiple data points via matplotlib but getting these datapoints seems to be kind of hard. I want to show the dependance of two specific combustion variables.
My approach was to create a loop and for every step to create one of these datapoints and and plot all of them in the end.
I tried to create variables which depend on the index name but turns out the code I used does not work.

%matplotlib inline
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as nm
from **future** import division
import cantera as ct

for i in range(50,151):
    x_i = i/100

The thing is every loop overwrites the existing variable x_i
So I end up with one variable x_i in the end.
What I want is every loop to create a new variable x_1, x_2 x_3, x_4 and so on.
Is there an easy way to do that?

Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use an dictionary:

```
x={}
for i in range(50,151): x[i] = i/100
```

or a list

```
x=[]
for i in range(50,151): x.append(i/100)
```